# Cambiar el formato de fecha de Y-m-d a d-m-Y

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando cambiar el formato de fecha de Y-m-d a d-m-Y en PHP, pero no logro hacerlo. Les dejo mi código.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE Nombre NOT LIKE '' ORDER By id_alumno LIMIT 25";

if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
    $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE id_alumno LIKE '%$q%' OR Nombre LIKE '%$q%' OR Numero LIKE '%$q%' OR Compa   LIKE '%$q%' OR Fechai LIKE '%$q%' OR Fechare LIKE '$q' "; 
}
 
$resultado = $conn->query($query);
$convert = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
$converted = implode('Fechare', array_reverse(explode('Fechai', $convert)));
```

Comment: Buenas, Humberto, bienvenido al sitio. No queda claro cuál es el origen de la fecha que quieres cambiar de formato, es decir, ¿de donde viene? ¿La estás intentando recuperar de la BBDD? Si es este el caso, puedes emplear la función DATE_FORMAT para recuperarla en el formato que quieras https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Si es desde mi BD donde estoy llamando la fecha, ya intente con DATE_FORMAT y no cambia.

Comment: ¿De qué tipo has declarado la columna fecha en la tabla alumnos en la base de datos?

Comment: La agregue de tipo date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te indicaba en los comentarios, puedes usar la función [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) de MySQL para obtener la fecha directamente formateada de la base de datos.

No sé la estructura exacta de tu tabla ALUMNOS, pero supongamos que es algo parecido a esto

```
CREATE TABLE ALUMNOS (  
    ID INT NOT NULL,  
    NOMBRE VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,  
    FECHA_ALTA DATE,  
    ADDRESS CHAR (25),  
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)  
);
```

Insertemos unos cuantos datos de prueba usando la fecha actual - CURDATE() -con variaciones como FECHA_ALTA

```
INSERT INTO ALUMNOS (ID, NOMBRE, FECHA_ALTA, ADDRESS) VALUES (1, 'PEDRO', CURDATE(), 'CASA PEDRO');
INSERT INTO ALUMNOS (ID, NOMBRE, FECHA_ALTA, ADDRESS) VALUES (2, 'JUAN', CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY, 'CASA JUAN');
INSERT INTO ALUMNOS (ID, NOMBRE, FECHA_ALTA, ADDRESS) VALUES (3, 'IGNACIO', CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 DAY, 'CASA IGNACIO');
INSERT INTO ALUMNOS (ID, NOMBRE, FECHA_ALTA, ADDRESS) VALUES (4, 'DANIEL', CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 DAY, 'CASA DANIEL');
INSERT INTO ALUMNOS (ID, NOMBRE, FECHA_ALTA, ADDRESS) VALUES (5, 'ALFONSO', CURDATE() + INTERVAL 4 DAY, 'CASA ALFONSO');
```

Si ejecutamos esta consulta constatamos que podemos obtener la fecha de alta en el formato deseado

```
SELECT ID, NOMBRE, FECHA_ALTA, DATE_FORMAT(FECHA_ALTA, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM ALUMNOS;
```

Resultado

```
ID  NOMBRE  FECHA_ALTA  DATE_FORMAT(FECHA_ALTA, '%d-%m-%Y')
1   PEDRO   2021-06-28  28-06-2021
2   JUAN    2021-06-29  29-06-2021
3   IGNACIO 2021-06-30  30-06-2021
4   DANIEL  2021-07-01  01-07-2021
5   ALFONSO 2021-07-02  02-07-2021
```

Puedes comprobarlo pinchando [aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4be31/1/0)

Comment: Mucas gracias !! me resulto de esa manera

Answer (score 1):

En tu código me falta algo: los separadores de las mes dia año. ´Te desgloso las sentencias por claridad, parto de la fecha que hab´ras leído de la fila:

```
$fecha  = $resultado->fetch_assoc()['campodelafecha'];
//Converitr fecha en array, para separador de fecha en la tabla la barra /
$arFecha = explode('/',$fecha);  
//ahora inviertes el array fecha
$arInvFecha = array_reverse($arFecha);
//Por último pegas los elementos del array mediante la /
$final = implode('/',$arInvFecha);
echo $final;
```

Pero también puedes usar una expresión regular

```
$fecha  = $resultado->fetch_assoc()['campodelafecha'];
$final = preg_replace('/(\d{2,4}).(\d{1,2}).(\d{1,2})/', '${3}/${2}/${1}',$fecha);
```

La segunda es más simple ¿no?
Y siempre queda usar objetos DateTime, quizás aún más sencillo

```
$fecha  = $resultado->fetch_assoc()['campodelafecha'];
$final = date_create($fecha)->format('d/m/yy');
```

Y seguro que aún hay alguna otra forma :)

Answer (score 0):

Usa

```
fecha=date_format(date_create($row['campo_fecha']),'d/m/Y');
```

pero al parecer te falta leer un renglón desde tu resultado (conjunto de registros)

```
$row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías primero guardar en una variable de PHP la fecha que tienes en formato Y-m-d para después hacer la conversión a d-m-Y mediante `strtotime()` y `date()`.

```
$converted = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($fechaI));
```

(Consulta la documentación para [date](https://www.php.net/strtotime) y [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime) desde el sitio oficial de PHP)